# Find derivative with respect to $\lambda_i$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to get this formula's derivative with respect to $\lambda_i$ but I can't. I tested with multiple online calculators but they fail to do so too. Can anyone help me?

In each iteration from $i$ to $n$, we have a $\lambda_i$ in numerator and sum of all lambdas in denominator including $i$-th lambda itself:

$$
e_k = \frac 1 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ki} \frac{e^{\lambda_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^n e^{\lambda_j}} - d_k \right)^2.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to proceed step by step. I will denote by $\partial_i$ the partial derivative with respect to $\lambda_i$.

Let me first consider the quantity
$$
E := \sum_{j=1}^n e^{\lambda_j}.
$$
You have $\partial_i E = e^{\lambda_i}$.

Then you are interested in
$$
e_k = \frac 1 2 \left( \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{b_{k \ell} e^{\lambda_{\ell}}}{E} - d_k \right)^2
$$

Hence
$$
\begin{split}
\partial_i e_k & = \left( \frac{b_{ki} e^{\lambda_i}}{E} - \frac{\partial_i E}{E^2} \sum_{\ell=1}^n b_{k\ell}e^{\lambda_\ell}  \right) \left( \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{b_{k \ell} e^{\lambda_{\ell}}}{E} - d_k \right) \\
& = \frac{e^{\lambda_i}}{E} \left( b_{ki} - \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{b_{k\ell}e^{\lambda_\ell}}{E}  \right) \left( \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{b_{k \ell} e^{\lambda_{\ell}}}{E} - d_k \right).
\end{split}
$$